# jquery draggable / sortable with disabled items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Using the include and exclude example, I am trying to make it so if two items are excluded and item can't be dropped between them.

Review the url;
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

The top example is almost perfect except item's can't be dropped before or after the lists (move item 4 to the top, then try and put item 4 back, wont let you).

In the second example items can be put before/after and between the disabled items, which again is half way to what I want.

Is there a way to make it so disabled items can't be inserted between?

Comment: Is the currently accepted answer what you want? See my comments. I was going to give this another look tomorrow if it hasn't been solved but if you don't need an answer I won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following fiddle has a working example if you know that all the disabled options are going to be next to each other. It adds a dropable spot just after the last disabled spot.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxb4w/)

```
 $(function () {
     $("#sortable1").sortable({
         items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled),li.ui-state-disabled:last-child"
     });
     $("#sortable2").sortable({
         cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
     });
     $("#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li").disableSelection();
 });
```

Comment: You can't put items at the top of the list again

Comment: As Ryan said, you can't add items to the top of the list, just need a first-child. Also need to add a cancel so you can't drag a disabled item if it's last or first. Fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/fazBS/

Comment: In this updated example you can put items in between the disabled items